# Quadratic interaction term dropping out in Stata but not in R

Tags: r, regression, stata

With the same data and the same model specification, Stata is dropping one of the terms from my model while R seems to run it just fine.

For example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(broom)

foo <- structure(list(inc = c(25545, 24879, 8843, 31668, 20335.25, 32625, 
                              21060, 15633.75, 31267.5, 10505, 5167, 33926, 22050, 44863, 11731.875, 
                              21659, 31927.5, 16235, 56647, 7751, 4343, 29402, 40756.5, 12779, 
                              28030, 29452.5, 28650, 15925, 92692, 3789, 44887, 6201, 38373.75, 
                              25511, 45837, 27500, 27171, 7984, 15925, 18947, 12870, 42234.75, 
                              49813.5, 28490, 38373.75, 10040.625, 30150, 15406, 14015, 45000), 
                      sex = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                        2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                        1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                        2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("male", "female"), class = "factor"), 
                      year = c(1993, 1978, 1993, 1985, 2002, 1996, 2016, 2006, 
                               2006, 1994, 1998, 1978, 2012, 1985, 2002, 1986, 2014, 1994, 
                               1980, 1998, 1988, 1978, 2004, 1983, 1982, 2008, 1994, 2012, 
                               1996, 1998, 2000, 1998, 2006, 1989, 1976, 1987, 2004, 1990, 
                               2012, 1998, 2016, 2002, 2004, 2010, 2006, 2008, 1989, 1996, 
                               1986, 1987)), 
                 row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

foo %<>%
  mutate(year2 = year * year)

lm(data = foo,
   inc ~ sex*year + sex*year2) %>%
  tidy
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>   term                estimate   std.error statistic p.value
#>   <chr>                  <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)      -63645382.   97555833.     -0.652   0.518
#> 2 sexfemale        164988796.  150579599.      1.10    0.279
#> 3 year                 64070.      97815.      0.655   0.516
#> 4 year2                  -16.1        24.5    -0.657   0.514
#> 5 sexfemale:year     -165546.     150810.     -1.10    0.278
#> 6 sexfemale:year2         41.5        37.8     1.10    0.277
```

The results above from R are what I expect.

However, in Stata, the `sexfemale:year2` interaction term gets dropped.

Using `RStata`:

```
library(RStata)
options("RStata.StataPath" = "") # you path here
options("RStata.StataVersion" = ) # your version here

stata("reg inc i.sex#c.year i.sex#c.year2 i.sex c.year c.year2",
      data.in = foo)
#> . reg inc i.sex#c.year i.sex#c.year2 i.sex c.year c.year2
#> note: 2.sex#c.year2 omitted because of collinearity
#> 
#>       Source |       SS       df       MS              Number of obs =      50
#> -------------+------------------------------           F(  4,    45) =    3.36
#>        Model |  3.0037e+09     4   750914046           Prob > F      =  0.0173
#>     Residual |  1.0058e+10    45   223510687           R-squared     =  0.2300
#> -------------+------------------------------           Adj R-squared =  0.1615
#>        Total |  1.3062e+10    49   266564022           Root MSE      =   14950
#> 
#> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#>          inc |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
#> -------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
#>   sex#c.year |
#>      female  |   287.9784   427.8164     0.67   0.504    -573.6881    1149.645
#>              |
#>  sex#c.year2 |
#>      female  |          0  (omitted)
#>              |
#>          sex |
#>      female  |  -589746.3   854533.4    -0.69   0.494     -2310865     1131372
#>         year |  -5771.122   74562.38    -0.08   0.939    -155947.5    144405.2
#>        year2 |   1.391068   18.68956     0.07   0.941    -36.25164    39.03378
#>        _cons |    6009728   7.44e+07     0.08   0.936    -1.44e+08    1.56e+08
#> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If you reverse `inc` and `year` (i.e., if you regress `year` on `inc` and an `inc*inc` variable, both interacted with `sex`), you get six terms as expected, and results from Stata and R agree. If you tell R to omit the term that Stata is dropping, they'll agree then too. I cannot seem to get Stata to give me all six terms with the original model.

What am I missing?

Here's Stata code to reproduce the dataset into Stata directly:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input double inc long sex double(year year2)
    25545 2 1993 3972049
    24879 2 1978 3912484
     8843 2 1993 3972049
    31668 1 1985 3940225
 20335.25 1 2002 4008004
    32625 1 1996 3984016
    21060 1 2016 4064256
 15633.75 2 2006 4024036
  31267.5 2 2006 4024036
    10505 2 1994 3976036
     5167 2 1998 3992004
    33926 1 1978 3912484
    22050 2 2012 4048144
    44863 1 1985 3940225
11731.875 1 2002 4008004
    21659 2 1986 3944196
  31927.5 2 2014 4056196
    16235 1 1994 3976036
    56647 1 1980 3920400
     7751 2 1998 3992004
     4343 1 1988 3952144
    29402 1 1978 3912484
  40756.5 1 2004 4016016
    12779 1 1983 3932289
    28030 1 1982 3928324
  29452.5 1 2008 4032064
    28650 1 1994 3976036
    15925 1 2012 4048144
    92692 1 1996 3984016
     3789 2 1998 3992004
    44887 1 2000 4000000
     6201 2 1998 3992004
 38373.75 1 2006 4024036
    25511 2 1989 3956121
    45837 1 1976 3904576
    27500 2 1987 3948169
    27171 1 2004 4016016
     7984 2 1990 3960100
    15925 2 2012 4048144
    18947 2 1998 3992004
    12870 2 2016 4064256
 42234.75 1 2002 4008004
  49813.5 2 2004 4016016
    28490 1 2010 4040100
 38373.75 1 2006 4024036
10040.625 2 2008 4032064
    30150 1 1989 3956121
    15406 2 1996 3984016
    14015 2 1986 3944196
    45000 1 1987 3948169
end
label values sex sex
label def sex 1 "male", modify
label def sex 2 "female", modify
```

Comment: I think you should be able to do `reg inc i.sex##c.year##c.year`

Comment: I assume you mean `reg inc i.sex##c.year##c.year2`, but no you still only get 5 terms.

Comment: No, I was suggesting `i.sex##c.year##c.year` so that Stata would create the quadratic term itself.

Comment: Ah, okay. I still get 5 terms. Appreciate the suggestion, though.

Comment: Ok, when we rescale `year` as you suggest, stata is able to estimate all 6 coefficients. To be sure, this isn't meant to be a sensible model, just the smallest model with the smallest data necessary to reproduce the issue. This suggests Stata has stricter criteria for when terms are dropped compared to R. So I guess the meta question is what are those criteria, and how do they differ from R's. Any thoughts? The stata documentation doesn't seem to go into this level of detail, that I've found.

Comment: I suppose this means stata sets a lower threshold for collinearity than R. I'm a bit bothered by this behavior--even if the variables are poorly coded, I'd prefer the model still run than trying to "protect me from myself" as it were. The idea that stata has an unpublished threshold at which it's going to change your model is, to me, troubling.

Comment: @JamesPhillips I'm not trying to model a trend I think is actually in the data. This is a small example dataset I made just to illustrate the question.

Comment: Stata thinks that the correlation between `year` and `year2` is about  0.999996121207278543. I am happy to regard that as collinear for practical purposes. Your point about documentation is a serious one: perhaps you can tell us where for R in general or `lm()` in particular it is documented what it does or does not allow in these cases and why.

Comment: To me the main issue here is statistical. A parameterisation in terms of say (year - 2000) and its square is much easier to think about and at the same time cuts out problems with precision and instability.

Comment: @NickCox it looks like R will fit collinear terms up to the point at which the correlation is perfect. If R had an arbitrary threshold for this, you could find it by viewing the source code. I'm a little curious what this threshold is for Stata -- I suppose I could iterate to find it, since I can't view the source and it isn't documented. Obviously there's a statistical issue here, but there's also a difference in preference for default behavior.

Comment: You're right. The R source code deep under, or called by, `lm()` is accessible and the C and Mata source code under `regress` in Stata is not. R people rightly enjoy flagging this difference, but it seems that they exploit it much less frequently in practice. Not wanting to start a fight, just bemused. There are means to dig deeper in Stata: `search collinear` is a start.

Comment: @NickCox Fair enough -- no fights here either. Source availability aside, I'm curious what you make of stata's behavior here. I'd imagine there could be a real case, perhaps with a very high N, that someone could rightfully want estimates for two very highly correlated terms. Maybe that's not the type of user stata has in mind?

Comment: My insight into this particular issue is just one of experience in using `regress` for 28 years over versions of Stata since 2.05. First, almost always when a predictor is thrown out it is for the same reasons as in R, perfect collinearity. Second, I've seen this kind of thing only occasionally and so suspect that Stata is only a little more strict than R. Stata isn't written for idiots but for users who want to be smart even if they are learning. So, most of the time the user is expected to look at output of coefficients and standard errors and work out what is  a bad idea.

Comment: Avoiding calendar years as predictors is something I have warned about in various places, e.g. Cross Validated and Statalist.

Comment: The high p-values provide a clue.  Indeed, the eigenvalues of the covariance matrix of (year, year2, inc) range over nearly 13 orders of magnitude.  This totally wipes out the precision inherent in the least squares calculations (which typically is 12 to 13 orders of magnitude).  By including `year*year` in these models, you are just confusing the calculations with noise.  If you really think it must be included, then improve your chances at seeing the signal with `lm(inc ~ sex * poly(year, 2), foo)`.